# c++ destructor getting called 2 times on the same object?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {

public:

    Test()  { cout << "Constructor is executed\n"; }
    ~Test() { cout << "Destructor is executed\n";}
    void show()  {  this->Test::~Test(); }
};

int main() {

    Test t;
    t.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Constructor is executed
Destructor is executed
Destructor is executed
```

Question: If `t.show()` has already called the destructor on "this" object(i.e. current object), which causes "destructor is executed" to be displayed once, then what causes it to be displayed for the second time? Which object is getting destroyed in that case ?

Comment: Why are you wondering, if you call the destructor explicitely here: `this->Test::~Test();`? You should never do such BTW.

Comment: The second time it would be called, [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) is triggered

Comment: I think the question is OK. Ofc, it would trigger UB, and ofc one should not call destructor explicitly, but the question is when and why it's called second time. It's essentially the same as removing explicit call and asking where was it called at all.

Answer (score 8):

Automatic variables get destroyed when they go out of scope. `Test t` is an automatic variable which goes out of scope when `main` ends. That's the second time the destructor is being called. The first time is through `Test::show` since the function manually destroys the object pointed to by `this`.

Since, C++ follows the philosophy of not paying for what you don't use, there isn't a runtime check of any sort before invoking the destructor on automatic variables going out of scope. Of course, what *actually* happens on the second destructor call is UB. Beware of [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 3):

Pradhan has given you an easy to understand explanation, I'll share the particular rule that deals with explicit destructor calls on objects with automatic storage duration, found in section 3.8p8 of the Standard:

> If a program ends the lifetime of an object of type `T` with static, thread, or automatic storage  duration  and  if  `T`  has  a  non-trivial  destructor,  the  program  must  ensure  that  an  object  of  the original type occupies that same storage location when the implicit destructor call takes place; otherwise the behavior of the program is undefined.  This is true even if the block is exited with an exception.

You're violating this rule, so you get undefined behavior.

The "implicit destructor call" is described in 6.7p2:

> Variables  with  automatic  storage  duration  are  initialized  each  time  their  declaration-statement  is executed.  Variables with automatic storage duration declared in the block are destroyed on exit from the
>   block.